# Angular 2 way binding component - Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Trying to get two way binding to work but getting the expression changed after it was checked exception.  When mode changes to cancel and I want to reset the value to empty I get the exception.  I assume it is because I am emitting inside of a change cycle with a different value but do not know how to avoid?

```
<edit-field [mode]="mode" [(field)]="field"></edit-field>
```

My component is:

```
 export class EditFieldComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input('mode') mode: string;
      @Input('field') field: string;
      @Output('fieldChange') fieldChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

     ngOnChanges() {
         if(this.mode == 'cancel'){
         this.field = "";
         this.fieldChange.emit("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A way around that is to manually decouple 2-way binding: Bind an Input into the component and bind an Eventemitter in the component to the output, but don't use 'the same one'. That's the cleanest way when wanting 2-way binding to a component that has to manipulate the incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't like when change detection causes model changes. `ngOnChanges` is called by change detection.

Either move the code to another callback that doesn't cause this error (I think `ngAfterViewChecked` works) or use `setTimeout()`

```
 export class EditFieldComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input('mode') mode: string;
      @Input('field') field: string;
      @Output('fieldChange') fieldChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

     ngOnChanges() {
         if(this.mode == 'cancel'){
           setTimeout(() => {
             this.field = "";
             this.fieldChange.emit("");
           });
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish a lifecycle hook would work.  AfterViewCheck does not, I get the same exception.  Set timeout works but seems a little hacky.  For now I enabled prod mode.  Leaving question open in case there is a better solution for now.

Comment: Enabling prod mode is IMHO the worst approach. You could also try `ngAfterViewInit`. AFAIR there is at least one callback that works. The best approach would be to not change the model in `ngOnChanges`. What about making `field` a setter and add the code there? I don't know if `this.fieldChange.emit("")` will cause problems there.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit is only called once per component so that wont work.  How do I update the html to allow for a setter as you suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: `private _field: string;
@Input('field') set field(value:string) { this._field = value; /* other code */}; get field() :string { return this._vield; }`

Comment: I see. I missed that you want it to be called on every change. A setter might help. I don't remember if it works around the error message though.